# 2 Player setup not showing after 1 player mode is previously selected

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm a newbie ... I'm making a 2 player game. At the main menu, if 1 player mode is selected and then you play or go back to main menu and select 2 Player mode, the 2 player mode doesn't show the 2 player mode setup screen correctly.

If 2 player mode is selected before 1 player mode ever is, then it shows the 2 player mode setup screen fine. Below is my onePlayerViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kGameType] isEqualToString:@"1Player"])
{
    vwPlayer2.hidden=TRUE;

    if (IDIOM == IPAD){

        lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, lblHeading.frame.origin.y+100, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
        vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, vwCenter.frame.origin.y, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 644);
        vwLevel.frame = CGRectMake(vwLevel.frame.origin.x,vwLevel.frame.origin.y, vwLevel.frame.size.width, vwLevel.frame.size.height);
        vwPlayer1.frame = CGRectMake(vwPlayer1.frame.origin.x,vwPlayer2.frame.origin.y, vwPlayer1.frame.size.width, vwPlayer1.frame.size.height);
    }else {

        lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, 115, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
        vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, 187, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 200);
        vwLevel.frame = CGRectMake(vwLevel.frame.origin.x, 105, vwLevel.frame.size.width, vwLevel.frame.size.height);
    }


    lblHeading.text = @"1 Player";
    txtPlayerName1.text = @"Player 1";

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPlayerName1] length]!=0)
    {
        txtPlayerName1.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPlayerName1];
    }

}
else if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kGameType] isEqualToString:@"2Player"])
{
    vwPlayer2.hidden=FALSE;
    vwLevel.hidden=FALSE;


    if (IDIOM == IPAD){

        lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, lblHeading.frame.origin.y, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
        vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, vwCenter.frame.origin.y, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 644);
        vwPlayer1.frame = CGRectMake(vwPlayer1.frame.origin.x,vwPlayer1.frame.origin.y, vwPlayer1.frame.size.width, vwPlayer1.frame.size.height);
        vwPlayer2.frame = CGRectMake(vwPlayer2.frame.origin.x,vwPlayer2.frame.origin.y, vwPlayer2.frame.size.width, vwPlayer2.frame.size.height);
       vwLevel.frame = CGRectMake(vwLevel.frame.origin.x,vwLevel.frame.origin.y, vwLevel.frame.size.width, vwLevel.frame.size.height);
    }else{

        if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
        {
            lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, 89, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
            vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, 135, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 310);
        }
        else
        {
            lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, 72, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
            vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, 101, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 312);
        }



    }


    lblHeading.text = @"2 Players";
    txtPlayerName1.text = @"Player 1";
    txtPlayerName2.text = @"Player 2";

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPlayerName1] length]!=0)
    {
        txtPlayerName1.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPlayerName1];
    }

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPlayerName2] length]!=0)
    {
        txtPlayerName2.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPlayerName2];
    }
}
else
{
    vwPlayer2.hidden=TRUE;
    vwLevel.hidden=TRUE;

    if (IDIOM == IPAD){

        lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, lblHeading.frame.origin.y, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
        vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, vwCenter.frame.origin.y, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 644);

    }else{

        lblHeading.frame = CGRectMake(lblHeading.frame.origin.x, 115, lblHeading.frame.size.width, lblHeading.frame.size.height);
        vwCenter.frame = CGRectMake(vwCenter.frame.origin.x, 187, vwCenter.frame.size.width, 200);
    }


    lblHeading.text = @"Player";
    txtPlayerName1.text = @"Player 1";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKeyPath:kPlayerName1];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKeyPath:kPlayerName2];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:kTurn];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kWifiPlayerName] length]!=0)
    {
        txtPlayerName1.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:kWifiPlayerName];
    }
    else
    {
        txtPlayerName1.text = @"Player 1";
    }

}
```

I have tried using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"kGameType"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` but i'm guessing that I am putting it in the wrong place??

HomeViewController -

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if (!gameCenterEnabled)
{
     [self notAnimate];
}
else
{
    btnPlayer1.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer1.center.x, btnPlayer1.center.y, 0, 0);
    btnPlayer2.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer2.center.x, btnPlayer2.center.y, 0, 0);
    btnWifi.frame=CGRectMake(btnWifi.center.x, btnWifi.center.y, 0, 0);
    btnInfo.frame=CGRectMake(btnInfo.center.x, btnInfo.center.y, 0, 0);

    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *lbl4 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:4];

    lbl1.alpha=1.0;
    lbl2.alpha=1.0;
    lbl3.alpha=1.0;
    lbl4.alpha=1.0;

    lbl1.frame=CGRectMake(lbl1.center.x,lbl1.center.y,0,0);
    lbl2.frame=CGRectMake(lbl2.center.x,lbl2.center.y,0,0);
    lbl3.frame=CGRectMake(lbl3.center.x,lbl3.center.y,0,0);
    lbl4.frame=CGRectMake(lbl4.center.x,lbl4.center.y,0,0);

    btnInfo.alpha = 1.0;
    btnWifi.alpha = 1.0;
    btnPlayer1.alpha = 1.0;
    btnPlayer2.alpha = 1.0;

    imgLogo.frame=CGRectMake(imgLogo.frame.origin.x, -imgLogo.frame.size.height, imgLogo.frame.size.width, imgLogo.frame.size.height);
    vwBottom.frame = CGRectMake(vwBottom.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height+vwBottom.frame.size.height, vwBottom.frame.size.width, vwBottom.frame.size.height);


    [self viewLoadAnimationForLogo];
    [self animationOnButton];
    [self animationOnLabel];
    [self animationOnBottomButton];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
}
gameCenterEnabled = YES; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

 //Actions
 -(IBAction)btnActions:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSNumber *numTag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sender.tag];

{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults removeObjectForKey:kGameType];
    //do this for all your keys..
    [defaults synchronize];
}

self.view.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

switch (sender.tag)
{


    //1 Player button
    case 11:
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1Player" forKey:kGameType];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateSelection1" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        [self removeSubviewsbyAnimations];

        if (IDIOM == IPAD){
            [btnPlayer1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn1PlayerS_iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{

            [btnPlayer1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn1PlayerS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


        btnPlayer2.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer2.center.x,btnPlayer2.center.y,0, 0);
        btnWifi.frame=CGRectMake(btnWifi.center.x,btnWifi.center.y,0, 0);
        btnInfo.frame=CGRectMake(btnInfo.center.x,btnInfo.center.y,0, 0);
        btnPlayer1.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer1.frame.origin.x-btnPlayer1.frame.size.width/2, btnPlayer1.frame.origin.y-btnPlayer1.frame.size.height/2, btnPlayer1.frame.size.width*2.0, btnPlayer1.frame.size.height*2.0);
        btnPlayer1.alpha  = 0.0;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(performButtonAction:) withObject:numTag afterDelay:animationDuration];
        break;

    //2 Player button
    case 12:
    {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"2Player" forKey:kGameType];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateSelection2" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        [self removeSubviewsbyAnimations];

        if (IDIOM == IPAD){
           [btnPlayer2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn2PlayerS_iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{

          [btnPlayer2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn2PlayerS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }



        btnPlayer1.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer1.center.x,btnPlayer1.center.y,0, 0);
        btnWifi.frame=CGRectMake(btnWifi.center.x,btnWifi.center.y,0, 0);
        btnInfo.frame=CGRectMake(btnInfo.center.x,btnInfo.center.y,0, 0);
        btnPlayer2.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer2.frame.origin.x-btnPlayer2.frame.size.width/2, btnPlayer2.frame.origin.y-btnPlayer2.frame.size.height/2, btnPlayer2.frame.size.width*2, btnPlayer2.frame.size.height*2);
        btnPlayer2.alpha  = 0.0;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(performButtonAction:) withObject:numTag afterDelay:animationDuration+0.2];

        break;
    }

     // Wifi play button
    case 13:
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"WifiPlayer" forKey:kGameType];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateSelection3" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        [self removeSubviewsbyAnimations];


        if (IDIOM == IPAD){
            [btnWifi setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnWifiPlayS_iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
          [btnWifi setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnWifiPlayS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }




        btnPlayer1.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer1.center.x,btnPlayer1.center.y,0, 0);
        btnPlayer2.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer2.center.x,btnPlayer2.center.y,0, 0);
        btnInfo.frame=CGRectMake(btnInfo.center.x,btnInfo.center.y,0, 0);
        btnWifi.frame=CGRectMake(btnWifi.frame.origin.x-btnWifi.frame.size.width/2, btnWifi.frame.origin.y-btnWifi.frame.size.height/2, btnWifi.frame.size.width*2, btnWifi.frame.size.height*2);
        btnWifi.alpha  = 0.0;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(performButtonAction:) withObject:numTag afterDelay:animationDuration+0.2];
        break;


    //Info button
    case 14:
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateSelection4" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        [self removeSubviewsbyAnimations];

        if (IDIOM == IPAD){
            [btnInfo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnInfoS_iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
           [btnInfo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icnInfoS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


        btnPlayer1.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer1.center.x,btnPlayer1.center.y,0, 0);
        btnPlayer2.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer2.center.x,btnPlayer2.center.y,0, 0);
        btnWifi.frame=CGRectMake(btnWifi.center.x,btnWifi.center.y,0, 0);
        btnInfo.frame=CGRectMake(btnInfo.frame.origin.x-btnInfo.frame.size.width/2, btnInfo.frame.origin.y-btnInfo.frame.size.height/2, btnInfo.frame.size.width*2, btnInfo.frame.size.height*2);
        btnInfo.alpha = 0.0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(performButtonAction:) withObject:numTag afterDelay:animationDuration+0.2];

        break;

     //Setting & score button
    default:
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateSelection5" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        [self removeSubviewsbyAnimations];

        btnPlayer1.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer1.center.x,btnPlayer1.center.y,0, 0);
        btnPlayer2.frame=CGRectMake(btnPlayer2.center.x,btnPlayer2.center.y,0, 0);
        btnWifi.frame=CGRectMake(btnWifi.center.x,btnWifi.center.y,0, 0);
        btnInfo.frame=CGRectMake(btnInfo.center.x,btnInfo.center.y,0, 0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(performButtonAction:) withObject:numTag afterDelay:animationDuration-0.1];

        break;
}
```

}

Screenshots as I may not be very good at explaining what I mean

- [1 Player Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPJ25.png)
- [2 Player Mode after 1 Player Mode has been previously selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2JdA.png)

Any advice, greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please share your code for 2 player mode button.

Comment: Added, thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry but you forgot to attach your desired output for the 2 player mode image.

Comment: It wouldn't let me  ... here is one on Dropbox ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdrw6znowbm9kw4/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2029%20Dec%202016%2C%2012.40.01.png?dl=0

Comment: Any updates @RigelNetworksPvt.Ltd.